# Comparar Coordenadas

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps, gps

No meu mysql tenho uma coluna onde contem coordenadas de posicionamento vindo de um polígono, desenhado na api google maps, a questão é como posso comparar
as coordenada que tenho dentro da coluna com coordenada especifica vinda de um GET

Vou exemplificar:

```
// Exemplo
$lat  = $_GET['lat'];  // -22.970981
$long = $_GET['long']; // -43.217496 

$cordenada = $lat.','.$long;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM gps Where poligono = '$cordenada' ";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());

// ai daqui pra frente eu vou sozinho
if ($result existir ){
faço alguma coisa
}
```

Esse é só um exmplo grotesco pra poder passar a minha ideia

Tabela mysql

```
  +----------+--------+------+------------------------+-----+
  | id_cerca | in_out | nome |       poligono         | id  |
  +----------+--------+------+------------------------+-----+
  |     01   |  in    | Fim  | (-22.91602,-41.97678), |  2  |
  |          |        |      | (-22.94322,-42.11171), |     |
  |          |        |      | (-23.02634,-41.99945)  |     |
  +----------+--------+------+------------------------+-----+
```

Comment: Olá amigo, que tipo de comparação que você deseja realizar? Se essa coordenada específica que você recebeu esta dentro do polígono da api do google maps? Tente detalhar um pouco mais seu objetivo.

Comment: Ola amigo, é isso mesmo...  no mysql tenho uma coluna onde fica as cordenadas do poligono então só quero checar se estas coordenadas estão dentro do poligono

Comment: Tem uma questão dessa nesse post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950062/checking-if-a-longitude-latitude-coordinate-resides-inside-a-complex-polygon-in a idéia é converter a latitude e longitude em posições x e y dentro do mapa, e ai então comparar se essas coordenadas x e y estão dentro da área desse polígono.

Comment: Você precisa verificar se um ponto pertence a um polígono específico ou encontrar qual polígono num banco de dados pertence à coordenada especificada? Se for o segundo caso, é fundamental conhecer sua estrutura de dados.

Comment: Ola Amigo a cima coloque como esta minha tabela. e a principio preciso verificar se um ponto pertence a um polígono especifico . obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Você quer saber se um ponto está dentro da área de um poligono, é isso? Se sim, oque eu recomendo é você gravar o poligono no formato de geometria que o MySql oferece. Assim você pode fazer consultas desse tipo e outras (se um ponto está em uma linha, se linhas se cruzam, se ponto está em um poligono, etc.) veja um exemplo: `"SELECT points.name FROM polygons, points WHERE ST_CONTAINS(polygons.geom, Point(points.longitude, points.latitude)) AND polygons.name = 'California'";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para verificar se um ponto pertence a um polígono, você pode usar esse algoritmo:

```
class pointLocation {
  var $pointOnVertex = true; // Check if the point sits exactly on one of the vertices?

  function pointLocation() {
  }

  function pointInPolygon($point, $polygon, $pointOnVertex = true) {
    $this->pointOnVertex = $pointOnVertex;

    // Transform string coordinates into arrays with x and y values
    $point = $this->pointStringToCoordinates($point);
    $vertices = array();
    foreach ($polygon as $vertex) {
      $vertices[] = $this->pointStringToCoordinates($vertex);
    }

    // Check if the point sits exactly on a vertex
    if ($this->pointOnVertex == true and $this->pointOnVertex($point, $vertices) == true) {
      return "no vértice";
    }

    // Check if the point is inside the polygon or on the boundary
    $intersections = 0;
    $vertices_count = count($vertices);

    for ($i=1; $i < $vertices_count; $i++) {
      $vertex1 = $vertices[$i-1];
      $vertex2 = $vertices[$i];
      if ($vertex1['y'] == $vertex2['y'] and $vertex1['y'] == $point['y'] and $point['x'] > min($vertex1['x'], $vertex2['x']) and $point['x'] < max($vertex1['x'], $vertex2['x'])) { // Check if point is on an horizontal polygon boundary
        return "na borda";
      }
      if ($point['y'] > min($vertex1['y'], $vertex2['y']) and $point['y'] <= max($vertex1['y'], $vertex2['y']) and $point['x'] <= max($vertex1['x'], $vertex2['x']) and $vertex1['y'] != $vertex2['y']) {
        $xinters = ($point['y'] - $vertex1['y']) * ($vertex2['x'] - $vertex1['x']) / ($vertex2['y'] - $vertex1['y']) + $vertex1['x'];
        if ($xinters == $point['x']) { // Check if point is on the polygon boundary (other than horizontal)
          return "na borda";
        }
        if ($vertex1['x'] == $vertex2['x'] || $point['x'] <= $xinters) {
          $intersections++;
        }
      }
    }
    // If the number of edges we passed through is odd, then it's in the polygon.
    if ($intersections % 2 != 0) {
      return "dentro";
    } else {
      return "fora";
    }
  }

  function pointOnVertex($point, $vertices) {
    foreach($vertices as $vertex) {
      if ($point == $vertex) {
        return true;
      }
    }

  }

  function pointStringToCoordinates($pointString) {
    $coordinates = explode(",", $pointString);
    return array("x" => $coordinates[0], "y" => $coordinates[1]);
  }
}
```

Crédito e detalhes da implementação em http://assemblysys.com/php-point-in-polygon-algorithm/

Para usá-la, faça algo como:

```
// Obtenha o polígono do banco de dados e salve num array nesse formato, sabendo
// que o último ponto deve ser igual ao primeiro pra fechar o polígono
$poligono = array(
  "-22.91602,-41.97678",
  "-22.94322,-42.11171",
  "-23.02634,-41.99945",
  "-22.91602,-41.97678",
);

// Coloque as coordenadas obtidas pelo $_GET assim
$coordenada = "-22.91602,-41.97678";

$pointLocation = new pointLocation();

echo "o ponto ($coordenada): está ".
     $pointLocation->pointInPolygon($coordenada, $poligono).
     " do polígono";

// Saída: o ponto (-22.91602,-41.97678) está no vertice do polígono
```

Comment: Amigão... Perfeito Era isso mesmo que precisava,  agora só uma duvida... quando eu consulto o poligono do banco as coordenadas vem sem ASPAS como posso tratar isso?

Comment: Qual é o tipo de dados da coluna polígonos? Quando vc obtém ela no php, como ela se apresenta exatamente?

Comment: Amigão ele esta assim na coluna  (-22.891996181150216, -43.127254512695345), (-22.86529776201615, -43.09548266210936)

Comment: Se for uma string, você pode fazer assim https://gist.github.com/rodorgas/db0128db300445a6eb5dee9fe6319339 . Se não for bem isso, o ideal é abrir outra pergunta, assim conseguimos discutir o problema melhor sem desviar o foco da discussão aqui.